# Как сделать такой navbar адаптивным

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать такой навбар адаптивным для моб. устройств.Что именно надо менять?Чтоб в дальнейшем можно было бургер меню сделать

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1174px;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 68px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.main-nav__logo {
  margin-right: 180px;
}

.main-nav__menu {
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav__form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-nav__menu-item,
.main-nav__form-item {
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav__menu-item-link,
.main-nav__menu-item-link:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 45px;
  width: 102px;
  height: 12px;
  color: #314584;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 20.76px;
  letter-spacing: 0.18px;
}

.main-nav__form-item-dropdown-button {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #314584;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 20.76px;
  letter-spacing: 0.18px;
}

.main-nav__form-item-dropdown {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 140px;
}

.main-nav__form-item-dropdown-button {
  padding-left: 25px;
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav__form-item-dropdown-button::after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/arrow.png") no-repeat scroll center center;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 2px 0 2px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.main-nav__form-item-dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.main-nav__form-item {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav__form-item-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url("../img/Arrow_form.png") no-repeat 164px 24px;
  padding: 21px 80px 21px 21px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(25, 45, 51, 0.15);
  color: #ff3946;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header" id="header">
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <div class="main-nav__logo">
        <a class="main-nav__logo-link"><img src="img/Logo.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul class="main-nav__menu">
          <li class="main-nav__menu-item"><a class="main-nav__menu-item-link" href="#">Home.</a></li>
          <li class="main-nav__menu-item"><a class="main-nav__menu-item-link" href="#">About us.</a></li>
          <li class="main-nav__menu-item"><a class="main-nav__menu-item-link" href="#">Portfolio.</a></li>
          <li class="main-nav__menu-item"><a class="main-nav__menu-item-link" href="#">Blog.</a></li>
          <li class="main-nav__menu-item"><a class="main-nav__menu-item-link" href="#">Contact us.</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="main-nav__form">
          <li class="main-nav__form-item">
            <div class="main-nav__form-item-dropdown">
              <div class="main-nav__form-item-dropdown-button">EN</div>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">EN</a>
                <a href="#">RU</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__form-item"><input class="main-nav__form-item-button" type="button" value="Contact to us" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: !) В метатег вставьте `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`.  2) Для адаптивности, воспользуйтесь `@media` в css. 3) Если хотите выпадающее меню, можно воспользоваться JQuery `slideToggle()`. Советую почитать о всем что вам неизвестно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, вот так. Меняйте ширину экрана

https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/RwbjwdM

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
.nav-wrapper,
.main-nav__menu,
.main-nav__form {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.nav-wrapper {
    width: auto;
}
```

}